# How do I trigger a keyup event in this scenerio

Tags: javascript, events

How do I trigger a keyup event in this scenario

```js
function check(form) {
  form.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.target.value === "") {
      form.querySelector(".error").innerText = "required"
    } else {
      form.querySelector(".error").innerText = ""
    }
  })

  

}
check(document.querySelector("#form1"))
```

```html
<form id="form1">

  <label>Name</label> <br />
  <input type="text" />


            
<span class="error"> </span>

</form>
```

I want required to be placed without hard coding it. Currently it works only if i trigger a keyup event myself

Basically when I run this code required should be in the screen already since the input is empty

Comment: Displaying an "error" before the user has had a chance to take action is, to some peoples opinion, a bad user experience.  An error is a mistake the users have made.  In this case, you are loading the page into the state to begin with.  That is hardly the user's fault.

Comment: Just a random example I made up my goal is really the title

Comment: Use your favorite search engine and search for "javascript, dispatchEvent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```js
function check(form) {
  // Get all .error elements
  const errors = document.querySelectorAll('.error')
  // Set inner text to 'required'
  errors.forEach(error => error.innerText = 'required')

  form.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.target.value === "") {
      form.querySelector(".error").innerText = "required"
    } else {
      form.querySelector(".error").innerText = ""
    }
  })
}

check(document.querySelector("#form1"))
```

```html
<form id="form1">

  <label>Name</label> <br />
  <input type="text" />      
  <span class="error"></span>

</form>
```

### How it works

`querySelectorAll(.error)` creates an array of every element with the class `.error` then we create a for loop to loop through all elements with the class `.error` and set the `innerText` to required.

Comment: "without hard coding it"

Comment: oh sorry will change it

Comment: @jimmyjimmy just changed it without hard coding